# How to get custom input fields to show up on home page in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I created a product that requires custom fields.  I went through the tutorial and I have them working on the product page.

Working Fields on Product Page
[image]

Not working fields on Featured Product[image]

So there are two sessions.  Product-customizable-template (this is what this code is on).  When i create a product I have to select this template to be used.

The one used for the home page is a feature.  feature-product.liquid.  It clearly doesn't import any setting created on the product template.

```
 <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="product-form product-form-{{ section.id }}{% unless section.settings.show_variant_labels %} product-form--hide-variant-labels{% endunless %}" data-section="{{ section.id }}">
        {% comment %}
        Custom Information
        {% endcomment %}
        <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="four columns alpha">
                <label for="groom_name">Groom's First Name</label>
                <input required type="text" id="groom_name" name="properties[groom_name]" placeholder="Groom">
              </div> 
              <div>
                <label for="four_name">Bride's First Name</label>
                <input required type="text" id="bride_name" name="properties[bride_name]" placeholder="Bride">
              </div>
            </div>


            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input required type="text" id="last_name" name="properties[Last Name]" placeholder="Last Name">
            <label for="wedding_date">Wedding Date</label>
            <input required type="date" name="wedding_date">

            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input required type="text" id="city" name="properties[City]" placeholder="City">
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <input required list="state" name="state">
              <datalist id="state">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
              </datalist>
        </div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please post a link to the tutorial you used - not sure what steps you have taken.

Comment: Here is the tutorial: https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is make the fields required inputs (see the steps in "Make customization form fields required") in that tutorial.  Then the customers will have to go to the Product page to add the item to their cart.